# Selecting a variable name from a select element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

`var k="gtype"`

`alert($("#forma [name=gtype]"))` works but how do I use the variable `k` in the name selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("#forma [name="+k+"]");
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply by

```
alert($("#forma [name="+k+"]"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alert($("#forma [name="+k+"]"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also remember to enclose your selector string parameters into quotes, like this

```
alert($('#forma [name="'+k+'"]'));
```